Styling issues with angular web components
I am working on angular and have created a component that is required to be used as both an angular component by an angular application and as a custom web component to be used by another application based on genesis.
The component uses styles from it's component stylesheet, common app styling, global styles from other modules, and angular material styling.
The angular component on angular app works as expected but when the same component is used as a custom web component styling from outside the component stylesheet is not getting applied. And I am not using any encapsulation.

What is the solution to this problem?
How should the styling should be used while creating an angular web component
How to bundle all the styles properly?


please share the minimal reproducible code

a code snippet will be helpful. Also try using ::ng-deep for styling outside from component

It's a work related project and I can't share any code snippet.

It depends on how you are creating the web component, basically you have to use multiple techniques like, including the styles inside the component or having the scss import in the component.
CSS Tricks has a great article on this Styling a Web Component.
The :part pseudo-elements might help you!
HTML:
<h4><x-foo>
  #shadow-root
    <div part="some-box"><span>...</span></div>
    <input part="some-input">
    <div>...</div> /* not styleable
</x-foo></h4>

CSS:
x-foo::part(some-box) { ... }

/* nope */
x-foo::part(some-box) span { ... }

